# Exception: Repeated column in mapping for entity: column: hash (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, lombok

I am very much new to Hibernate framework and getting an exception while running the code:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: LeiRecord column: hash (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

This error i am getting in many places in SpringConfiguration, oracleDataDao and not understanding where the code is getting wrong as i have not defined repeated column in mapping

Answer (score 1):

You should have class `Address` annotated as `@Embeddable` and then reference its instances in `LeiRecord` entity for `addressLegal` and `addressHeadquearters`

```java
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address {

   private String firstAddr;
   private String nextAddr;
   //... etc.
}

@Getter
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BK_TEST")
@Immutable
public class LeiRecord {
// ...
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(
        {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "firstAddr",   column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_firstAddr")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "nextAddr",    column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_nextAddr")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "region",      column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_region")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "postalCode",  column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_postalCode")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city",        column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_city")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "country",     column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_country")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "mailRouting", column = @Column(name = "legalAddress_mailRouting"))
        }
    )
    private Address addressLegal;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(
        {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "firstAddr",   column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddress_firstAddr")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "nextAddr",    column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddress_nextAddr")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "region",      column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddress_region")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "postalCode",  column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddress_postalCode")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city",        column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddress_city")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "country",     column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddress_country")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "mailRouting", column = @Column(name = "headquartersAddr_mailRouting"))
        }
    )
    private Address addressHeadquarters;

    //... other entity fields

}
```

Comment: now i am getting different error as : Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [hash] in table [LEI_TEST]    in SpringCOnfiguration and oracleDataDao class files

Comment: i have updated my question with xml schema which i am trying to read

Comment: Is `LeiTest` the same table as `LeiRecord`?  I cannot see any info about its related entity class.

Comment: i dont understand hash is never column in my class or in database table

Comment: It seems there is another invalid embedded value in your entity:

```
 @Embedded
    private String registration;
```
You need to have class Registration annotated as Embeddable

Comment: yes you are right previously in my code it was  like ```private Registration registration``` which was throwing an error and i didnt understood if i need to create new Reigistration class so i have created it as: ```@Embedded private String registration```   which is incorrect...do you know how to get rid of this ?

Comment: As I wrote, you must create @Embeddable class Registration and use it similar to the `Address` class:
`@Embedded
private Registration registration;
`
You may not apply AttributeOverrides if you embed Registration only one time.
Also, you definitely need to clean up your database schema.

Comment: yes i understand that and what will be the entities i need to create in the Registration class  ? can you plese tell for example because i think its not repeated ? And clean up the database schema means the column name should be different ? i think this is very minor error which i am not understanding if it gets fix then everything will run normal

Comment: _what will be the entities i need to create in the Registration class?_  How could **I** know?? Especially after you removed all the relevant contents in your last edit :)
You may want to review this short article on [implementing Embedded and Embeddable entities](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable)